# A terminal opens fullscreen and nothing works

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, xfce

I've twice had the following problem (running Linux Mint 20 (xfce) on AMD 64 (8GB)):

While using shortcuts in apps for example Ctrl+F5 in Firefox, my fingers slipped (fast) and I accidentally hit some shortcut I didn't notice (because of speed) and suddenly the system was in Terminal mode asking for login, and there was no way of getting out if it.

There must be a shurtcut to start and to close this terminal, that overtakes the screen and locks you out.
I've tried search engines but find nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you press Ctrl-Alt-F5?
It gets you to text console #5.
Keep pressing one of horizontal cursor arrows with Alt till you get back to your graphics console.

Comment: This. On some systems, it's ALT-F<n>, like ALT-F5.  Try CTRL-ALT-F7, or ALT-F7, to get back to the virtual terminal with X-Windows running.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed.